# Why my highlight item quick show and disapper?

Tags: qt, qml

I write a simple `ListView` and want to highlight the item when keyboard arrow key pressed.
The program look like well but the highlight function work strange,it quickly show and the disapper in my eye.This not the effect I wanted,I want it always show highlight color when the current item is highlight.

```js
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Rectangle {
    width: 400
    height: 400

    Component {
        id: nameDelegate
        Rectangle {
            width: ListView.view.width
            height: 30

            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: index
                font.pixelSize: 14
            }
        }

    }

    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        spacing: 5
        focus: true
        model: 10
        delegate: nameDelegate

        highlight: Rectangle {
            width: ListView.view.width
            height: ListView.view.currentItem.height
            color: "lightGray"
        }
    }

}
```

---

**Add New Info**
If I change delegate item(rectangle) to below

```js
Rectangle {
    width: ListView.view.width
    height: 30
    color: "#ada"
    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: index
        font.pixelSize: 14
    }
}
```

And I want to the highligh item show lightgray when arrow key press, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

It's because of [stacking order](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#stacking-order-in-listview).

The highlight's default `z` value is `0`. Each delegate has `z` value of `1`, so by default the highlight is behind each delegate.

Your delegate has a white `Rectangle` as its background, so the highlight will not be visible.

You can either remove the white background from the delegate (e.g. just use a plain `Item` or set the `color` of the rectangle to be transparent) or increase the z value of the highlight. The latter will result in the text not being visible, though, so you would have to rethink how the highlight could look. For example, you could make it an underline instead of a solid block of colour:

```
ListView {
    anchors.fill: parent
    spacing: 5
    focus: true
    model: 10
    delegate: nameDelegate

    highlight: Item {
        z: 2
        Rectangle {
            width: parent.width
            height: 1
            y: parent.height - height
            color: "lightGray"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is good for me,but I really like solid block color when item highlight.You can see the lastest info of my post.

Comment: Your question is the same except for the colour used, so the answer is the same. Coincidentally it's the exact same problem that was recently discussed here: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-95261